# Inline code cannot find assembly reference

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, vs-web-site-project

I have inherited an old asp.net webform **WebSite** Application, one of my recent projects I moved all the code from the app_code folder to a separate library. This has worked out great except for one page.

The page in question has no code behind and just **uses embedded VB.NET code** to do some work.
The code needs to construct a type from the new library I created, Instead of looking for the type in the dll it looks in the App_Code dll and I get the following exception:

> Could not load type 'CybersourceSecurity' from assembly 'App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

So I added the Import NameSpace and the Assembly reference:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="EA.Legacy" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EA.Legacy" %>
```

Still I get the error.
Code Below:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableViewState="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="EA.Legacy" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EA.Legacy" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head runat="server">
        <title>Events and Adventures</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <%
        Dim ky As String
        Dim fm As Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim cybsSecurity As New EA.Legacy.CybersourceSecurity
        Dim ValidSignature As Boolean = False
        Try

            <Do a bunch of stuff that never happens because we blow up first.>

        Catch ext As Threading.ThreadAbortException
            'ignore

        Catch ex As Exception
            eventsvb.PageError(Me, ex, "CybersourceReceipt")

        Finally
            sb = Nothing
            cybsSecurity = Nothing

        End Try

    %>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Full Stack Trace bellow:

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CybersourceSecurity' from assembly 'App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>      ASP.accounting_cybs_receipt_form_aspx.__Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in 
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +315
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +48
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
>      System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5290

**[Edit]**
Note: This code works just fine in VS I can step through it with no exception, it only happens on the web server.

Comment: If you create a new page in the same folder, can you create a `CybersourceSecurity` instance from the codebehind of that new page?

Comment: Yes we have a bunch of other pages that use the CyberSourceSecurity Class in the code behind. I forgot to add I don't get this error in Visual studio, I can step through the code and it works fine it only happens on the webserver

Comment: Is this part of a web site "project", or a web application project?

Comment: Its a WebSite Project

Comment: It's important to say so - web site projects should be avoided, since they are different from any other kind of project in Visual Studio. One result of that is that those trying to help you will assume you are using a web application project and will give you bad answers.

Comment: Yeah thanks Ill add that in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out,The key was it works in VS and not on the server, once upon a time the site was compiled down entirely into dlls including the  aspx pages. I was able to repro the problem on the staging site then clean out the bin folder and the page started working. So I looked in the bin folder in production and found a dll with the same name as the aspx page,I deleted it, and all is well with the world.  My take away: every time we push a new build to production we need to clear out anything that's no longer part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

alright it's working on your VS because it's using the reference locally, but on your server there is no such a reference, to fix the issue you just follow the instruction below:

**Step 1** In Visual studio under your project solution click on **References** folder
[image]

**Step 2** Now right click on the a references that you want to embed them into your project and click on **Properties** , then you will see the **Copy Local** option is set to false, set it to **true**

[image]

Now save and rebuild your solution, then publish it on the server and that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a Web Site not a Web Application Project so there is no reference folder and all the dlls are copied into the bin directory by default. In addition that reference is used by other pages so I know its referenced correctly,  But Thanks